# Design a DFA that accepts numbers whose sum of digits is $2 \mod 3$

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> Design a DFA that accepts language $$L = \left\{ x \in \{ 0, 1, 2 \} : \text{ sum of digits in } x \text{ is } 2 \mod 3 \right\}$$

---

How to make a DFA for this? I have no idea how to solve this dfa problem. I have a solution by someone but I am not getting concept to start this solution.

Answer (score 1):

A good first step for designing automata is to think about what states you will need. Here, you would need to remember the sum – which is not possible with a DFA – but thankfully, we only need to remember the sum in mod3 arithmetic, which means it can only have three distinct values: 0, 1 or 2. Therefore, we can keep track of the sum mod 3 with a finite number of states.

Then you need to devise the state transitions between the states representing these values. A convenient fact of modular arithmetic to remember is that $a + b \equiv a - (n-b) \mod n$.